# Facebook graph api - Video with no cover image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I uploaded a video with app.

I found few problems. I am trying to fix other problem. But can't have a clue to fix this one.

Once the video is uploaded, It is displayed in facebook with just a play button without any cover / image. It is just blank and black.

I tried to set a parameter which will call a image from remote server as a cover image.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

```
$params['picture'] = "full_url/cover_1.png";
```

The other parameters are source of the video, title, and decription.
It is still blank and black.

Comment: will you please share your code? it may be helpful. Are u using Facebook SDK for your mobile ( ios or android ) Or just an HTML5 mobile app with any wrapper. ?

Comment: what is the url of the picture ? is that something fully defined and accessible by the crawler ? Also, what happens when you pass the link through the debugger ?